# I need to insert cookie value in hidden field of HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have cookies assigned to each user when they come to the website. I want to pass that value to the hidden field I get that result in my email when the form is submitted.

When I test that piece of code

```
$("input[name='dmform-1']").val(getCookie("OriginalSource")).change();
```

In the browser console, it populates the correct field value properly. However, it doesn't want to be added automatically when the form is submitted.

Here is the JavaScript I'm using to get cookie value and add it to the input field:

```
<script>
window.getCookie = function(OriginalSource) {
  var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + OriginalSource + '=([^;]+)'));
  if (match) return match[2];
}

function getcookies(){
$("input[name='dmform-1']").val(getCookie("OriginalSource")).change();
 };

</script>
```

And here is the HTML form:

```
<form method="post" class="dmRespDesignRow" locale="ENGLISH" id="1220309190" onSubmit="getcookies">
```

Name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dmform-1" id="1556014337" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-1" value="OriginalSource" id="1029389973" class=""/>
```